# Existing date formatting throws off pickadate.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Inputs are pre-populated in my date fields with the format 2013-10-25 (it's the format they're stored in the database). When I then click the input to open pickadate, it opens to the wrong date. For example, if my input is pre-populated with 2013-12-11, pickadate will open to December 12, 1900. This also happens when I use the API to get the date:

```
$("#date").pickadate({
    selectYears: true,
    format: 'mmmm d\, yyyy',
    formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    onStart: function() {
        var picker = this;
        console.log(picker.get('select', 'mmmm d\, yyyy'));
    }
});
```

Is this a bug or should I be formatting the date myself onStart to prevent this? I've been trying to use "get" and "set" in the API with no luck. Using version 3.3.1.

Comment: You should populate the field with a date in the `format` format, not `formatSubmit` format.

Answer (score -1):

This code works for me -

```
var $input = $('.datepicker').pickadate();
var picker = $input.pickadate('picker');
picker.set('select', [2013,3,20]);
```

This is not a bug since it is working on the official site.